# How to detect/identify when the User clears all the push notifications from the NotificationCenter tray in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

We can detect/identify if the User clears each push notification explicitly at

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
```

but is there any way that When the User clears all the push notifications at once from the notification center tray.

Any help from anyone is very much appreciated.

I have tried setting up the UNNotitificationCategory for each push notifications but still no luck in getting this callback at

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
```

for clearing all the push notifications at once.

Comment: No, there is no visibility of the state of notifications that the user doesn't actually interact with

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to detect if the user has cleared all the notifications.

But u can try a workaround as follows.

Following function give the count of the delivered notifications.

```
func hasUserClearedNotifications() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications { (notifications) in
        let deliveredCount = notifications.count
    }
}
```

U have to keep checking that count periodically inside ur application. If that count goes to zero or the count drops suddenly then there is a high chance that user have cleared the notifications.

(Please note that this is a workaround. Not a best practise)